# Proving the existence of God

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language, theology

I was wondering whether anyone has done, or attempted to do, any work, trying to prove the existence of God. If so, scary works such work be centered about, what would it do, or consist of, or what approach would it even take?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the famous [ontological argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontological_argument) in *a priori* philosophy and many philosophers and logicians had tried as described in the ref...

Answer (score 2):

Most people who believe in God or have a religious faith of some kind do not come to it through "proving" the existence of God/Heaven or Hell. It's generally by a non-rational faculty.

Kant wrote a thick tome proving this to everybody which really ought to have been blindingly obvious to anyone who has any understanding of religion.

Comment: And what was this trick tome?

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson: What "trick tome"? I mentioned only a "thick tome."

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson: I'm not interested in "trick" questions ...